# How to make FormValidator::Simple to use the same rule for multiple keys?

Tags: perl, validation

Now it just looks very verbose:

```
key1 => THE_SAME_RULE,
key2 => THE_SAME_RULE,
..
keyn => THE_SAME_RULE,
```

Is there a way to express this in more concise manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a loop, and you want it inside an expression. That begs for `map`.

```
( map { $_ => THE_SAME_RULE } qw( key1 key2 .. keyn ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

The values are just data so you could have an extra variable that holds the rule and then refer to that variable when building your rule set. For example:

```
my $email  = ['NOT_BLANK', 'EMAIL_LOOSE'];
my $result = FormValidator::Simple->check( $query => [
    mail1 => $email,
    mail2 => $email,
] );
```

In theory, you could build up a whole library of rules and then use that library everywhere:

```
my $result = FormValidator::Simple->check( $query => [
    mail  => $AskersRules::EMAIL,
    phone => $AskersRules::PHONE,
    # etc.
] );
```

Then you wouldn't have to repeat yourself and you'd have a central library for both re-use and testing purposes.

I think you can also do this:

```
{ ks => [ 'key1', 'key2' ] } => THE_SAME_RULE
```

if that's what you're after. From the [fine manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FormValidator%3a%3aSimple):

```
my $result = FormValidator::Simple->check( $q => [
    { mails => ['mail1', 'mail2'] } => [ 'DUPLICATION' ],
] )
```

Comment: The most concise should be something like `[mail1, mail2] => $email`,does it support something like this?

Comment: @asker: Something like in my update perhaps? There's a bit of extra syntax involved and I'm not sure if that's what you're after. I usually use the library approach so that everything lines up in nice columns.